# GUI doesn't move accordingly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i'm trying to display pitch, roll and yaw indications in term of graphic so i build an GUI using user control in visual basic. this is my code for the GUI only.

```
Private g As Graphics

Private _roll_angle As Double
Public Property roll_angle() As Double
    Get
        Return _roll_angle
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _roll_angle = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
Private _pitch_angle As Double
Public Property pitch_angle() As Double
    Get
        Return _pitch_angle
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        _pitch_angle = value
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property


Private Sub ArtificialHorizon_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Function pitch_to_pix(ByVal pitch As Double) As Integer
    Return pitch / 35.0 * Me.Height / 2
    'Return pitch / 45.0 * Me.Height / 2
End Function

Private Sub ArtificialHorizon_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    g = e.Graphics
    g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

    g.Clear(Me.BackColor)
    Dim sin As Double = Math.Sin(roll_angle / 180 * 3.14)

    g.ResetTransform()
    '        g.FillRegion(Brushes.White, New Region(New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)))

    ' rounded rectangle
    Dim path As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
    Dim r As Single = 50
    path.AddArc(0, 0, r, r, 180, 90)
    path.AddArc(Me.Width - r, 0, r, r, 270, 90)
    path.AddArc(Me.Width - r, Me.Height - r, r, r, 0, 90)
    path.AddArc(0, Me.Height - r, r, r, 90, 90)
    'path.AddEllipse(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
    path.CloseFigure()
    g.SetClip(path)

    g.TranslateTransform(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)

    g.RotateTransform(roll_angle)
    g.TranslateTransform(0, pitch_to_pix(pitch_angle))

    ' chocolate
    Dim b As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New RectangleF(-Me.Width, 0, Me.Height * 2, Me.Width * 2), Color.FromArgb(255, 219, 140, 21), Color.Brown, Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Vertical)
    g.FillRectangle(b, New RectangleF(-Me.Width * 2, +1, Me.Height * 4, Me.Width * 4))

    g.RotateTransform(180)

    ' color.aqua
    b = New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(New RectangleF(-Me.Width, -1, Me.Height * 2, Me.Width * 2), Color.FromArgb(255, 28, 134, 186), Color.DarkBlue, Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.Vertical)
    g.FillRectangle(b, New RectangleF(-Me.Width * 2, 0, Me.Height * 4, Me.Width * 4))




    g.ResetTransform()
    Dim w2 As Single = Me.Width / 2
    Dim s As Single = Me.Width / 38
    g.TranslateTransform(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)
    g.RotateTransform(45)
    g.TranslateTransform(-w2 + s, 0)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), 0, 0, s * 2, 0)
    g.TranslateTransform(+w2 - s, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 2, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 2, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 3, 0)
    'g.DrawString("0°", New System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 9), Brushes.White, -w2 + 40, -4)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 2, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 2, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(15)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 2), -w2 + s, 0, -w2 + s * 3, 0)
    'g.DrawString("+45°", New System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 9), Brushes.White, -w2 + 40, -4)


    g.ResetTransform()

    Dim length As Single = Me.Width / 4
    Dim notch As Single = Me.Width / 30
    g.TranslateTransform(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 3), -length + notch * 2, 0, -notch, 0)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 3), notch, 0, length - notch * 2, 0)
    g.DrawArc(New Pen(Color.White, 3), -notch, -notch, notch * 2, notch * 2, 180, -180)

    g.ResetTransform()

    ' driehoekje
    Dim ww As Single = Me.Width / 38
    g.TranslateTransform(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)
    g.RotateTransform(-90 + roll_angle)
    path = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
    path.AddLine(w2 - ww * 3, 0, w2 - ww * 4, ww)
    path.AddLine(w2 - ww * 4, -ww, w2 - ww * 4, ww)
    path.AddLine(w2 - ww * 4, -ww, w2 - ww * 3, 0)
    g.FillRegion(Brushes.White, New Region(path))
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 1), w2 - ww * 3, 0, w2 - ww * 4, ww)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 1), w2 - ww * 4, -ww, w2 - ww * 4, ww)
    g.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.White, 1), w2 - ww * 4, -ww, w2 - ww * 3, 0)



    g.ResetTransform()
    g.ResetClip()
    path = New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
    path.AddPie(New Rectangle(ww * 3, ww * 3, Me.Width - ww * 6, Me.Height - ww * 6), 0, 360)
    g.SetClip(path)

    g.TranslateTransform(Me.Width / 2, Me.Height / 2)
    g.RotateTransform(roll_angle)
    g.TranslateTransform(0, pitch_to_pix(pitch_angle))
    For i As Integer = -80 To 80 Step 10
        drawpitchline(g, i)
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub drawpitchline(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal pitch As Double)
    Dim w As Single = Me.Width / 8
    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, -w, pitch_to_pix(-pitch + 5), w, pitch_to_pix(-pitch + 5))
    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, -w * 5 / 3, pitch_to_pix(-pitch), w * 5 / 3, pitch_to_pix(-pitch))
    g.DrawString(pitch, Me.Font, Brushes.White, -w * 75 / 30, pitch_to_pix(-pitch) - 5)
    g.DrawString(pitch, Me.Font, Brushes.White, w * 2, pitch_to_pix(-pitch) - 5)
End Sub

Private Sub drawrollline(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal a As Single)
    Dim w2 As Single = Me.Width / 2


    g.RotateTransform(a + 90)
    g.TranslateTransform(-w2 + 10, 0)
    g.DrawLine(Pens.White, 0, 0, 20, 0)
    g.TranslateTransform(10, 5)
    g.RotateTransform(-a - 90)
    g.DrawString("" & (a) & "°", New System.Drawing.Font("sans-serif", 9), Brushes.White, 0, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(+90 + a)
    g.TranslateTransform(-10, -5)
    g.TranslateTransform(+w2 - 10, 0)
    g.RotateTransform(-a - 90)
End Sub
```

then i added in a button to give some testing readings. code below

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AH.roll_angle = 45
    AH.pitch_angle = 10
End Sub
```

when the button is clicked, the GUI is supposed to turn/rotate according to the inputs. however, it stays still (btw, code is able to debug thou and the graphic did show up). i believe it's because i did not refer to the AH variable in my painting. can someone pls give me a guide on this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what is AH, but if you replace this variable with Me in Button1_Click it works (at least, a whole rotation, then it starts to go outside the frame).

Comment: AH stands for artificial horizon, which i named as the variable. and yes, it worked. but after i stop debugging, the button disappeared and i tried to do the same thing again, and this time round, no button was shown. may i know why?

Comment: Your code is a bit complex and the paint event can become a bit tricky. But usually the involved problems have to do with artifacts or with the form getting frozen. Usually if it works once it should work more (and it works fine with me). Where I locate the button didn't find any problem, but bear in mind that you are changing the whole layout of the main form and thus this is what makes the button disappear. Set break points and keep track of the values to understand where it starts to go wrong (as said, in my case, was after the first whole rotation).

Comment: PS: bear in mind that I tested your code associated to the main form (= written as such in its initial Class); that's why I recommended you to change AH to Me and asked about what AH is; I guess that it is a control, like a panel.

Answer (score 0):

I might have something which can be used, I created this to display azimuth heading of parabolic antenna.

1. the heading is using simple pen
2. superimpose on top of circle image
3. the pen will rotate according to the degree movement

With **3** main functions

1. **DrawAntenna()** --> draw the pen/line
2. **FindPointOnCircle()** --> find end point of the pen (start point always center of circle)
3. **RotateAntenna()** --> this will rotate the pen and updating the image accordingly
4. call RotateAntenna from your function (e.g. TextChanged), and pass the change angle to RotateAntenna
5. One key thing is to do a refresh on the image whenever the angle change, this will provide rotate effect.
6. I suggest making this on a different thread, as not to bogged down your main thread, because usually this data acquisition for the azm/elv/roll will happen continuously.

**Down to the code:**

```
Private Function FindPointOnCircle(ByVal originPoint As Point, ByVal radius As Double, ByVal angleDegrees As Double) As Point
        Dim x As Double = radius * Math.Cos(Math.PI * angleDegrees / 180.0) + originPoint.X
        Dim y As Double = radius * Math.Sin(Math.PI * angleDegrees / 180.0) + originPoint.Y
        Return New Point(x, y)
 End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub DrawAntenna(ByVal originPoint As Point, ByVal endPoint As Point, ByVal g As Graphics, Optional ByVal aPen As Pen = Nothing)
        If aPen Is Nothing Then
            Using BluePen = New Pen(Color.Blue)
                BluePen.Width = 2
                g.DrawLine(BluePen, originPoint.X, originPoint.Y, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y)
            End Using
        Else
            g.DrawLine(aPen, originPoint.X, originPoint.Y, endPoint.X, endPoint.Y)
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub RotateAntenna(ByVal ang As Double, ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal typeOfDisplay As Integer)

        ' Radius of 95% of half the width of the panel
        Dim radius As Double = (Me.picDestTop.Width / 2) * 0.95

        ' Origin half of width and height of panel
        Dim origin As New Point(Me.picDestTop.Width / 2, Me.picDestTop.Height / 2)
        Select Case typeOfDisplay

            Case displayAntenna.DisplayTop
                'rotate start at 270deg, pointing up

                Dim antennaDegrees As Double = ang + 170
                'find point
                Dim secondsPoint As Point = FindPointOnCircle(origin, radius, antennaDegrees)
                Using p As New Pen(Color.Red)
                    p.Width = 5
                    DrawAntenna(origin, secondsPoint, g, p)
                End Using


            Case displayAntenna.DisplaySide
               'display elevation

            Case displayAntenna.DisplayRoll
               'display pitch


        End Select

        g.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

---

```
'azimuth
    Private Sub lblEncCurrent_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblEncCurrent.TextChanged
        Dim iint As Double
        Me.picDestTop.Refresh()
        iint = CDbl(lblEncCurrent.Text)
        If iint >= 360 Then
            iint = iint - 360
        End If
        RotateAntenna(iint, Me.picDestTop.CreateGraphics, displayAntenna.DisplayTop)
    End Sub
```

---

Hope this help!!. Thanks.